# /~user that points to /var/www/html

Tags: website

For a regular user named `smith` on a server, the symbol `/~smith` points at the root of `smith`'s web presence, his `public_html` directory.

Is there a similar contrivance for the main web directory of a server that lives at `/var/www/html/`?

Comment: What Web Server?  What ecactly are you asking - ie what would the "contrivance" be and how is it any different to https://x.y.z/smith looking in /var/www/html/smith ?

Comment: Check DOCUMENT_ROOT in your Web Server Configuration !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's literally just `/`.

The "main web directory" is only the main web directory *because* `/` is configured to point there, i.e. because it's configured to be the "document root" of the web server.

Meanwhile if some other directory is set as the document root, then there's no reason for the webserver to care about /var/www/html anymore, thus no special syntax for accessing it.

(Unless the webserver admin configures some. Usually no special syntax is built in, but almost anything could be added manually, using "aliases" and/or "rewrite rules", if the admin *wanted* to.

Even the "/~user/" shortcut isn't exactly built-in to the webserver – in Apache httpd it's provided by the mod_userdir module that the admin had to enable, but many other HTTP servers such as Nginx don't have any equivalent at all, so the server admin has to manually set up a rewrite rule to "/home/$1/public_html" to make it work.)

Comment: Thanks!  That worked. That mechanism keeps things sane as a site grows.